# selected row colour and selected cell colour

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview in which I want that when any cell of any row receives focus, its color and the color of full row in which is cell is should change and it should get back to normal when the focus goes to another row. I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

try CellContentClick event for capturing cell click as well as cell controls click

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Purple;
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
}
```

edit:
it is possible without events

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Purple;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.WhieSmoke;
```